# __init__ method implemented on application called inside the main method

Tags: python, class, initialization

This code is part of the main calculator application mentioned here: https://pastebin.com/ECA2AQzY

I am new to python and from my understanding, "self" is the first argument being passed automatically for each instance of a class. Here, I am confused whether "app" would be self? and Frame is some superclass?

I do not understand why **init** is called on Frame within a main **init** method?

Also, why is lambda needed? Can it just not be command = self.appendToDisplay("7"))

What was the need of calling grid method on "app" object when the grid is called in the class itself?

```
calculator = Tk()
calculator.title("Calculator")
calculator.resizable(0, 0)

#================================================
class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)
        self.createWidgets()
    #================================================
    def createWidgets(self):
        self.sevenButton = Button(self, font=("Helvetica", 11), text="7", 
        borderwidth=0, command=lambda: self.appendToDisplay("7"))
        self.sevenButton.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="NWNESWSE")

#================================================
app = Application(calculator).grid()
calculator.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to answer your questions in order:

1. `Application` intherrits from `Frame`, that is all methods implemented in `Frame` are also avaliable in `Application`. In addition `Application` can implement its own methods as well as override implementations in `Frame`. In the latter case, the implementations in `Application` replace the implementations in `Frame`. This is the case for the `__init__()` method. The method in `Application` replaces the one in `Frame`. Thus, the `Frame()` `__init__()` method is never called and that is typically not good, since there may be a lot of the functionallity in `Frame()` that needs explicit initialization. Therefore, `Application.__init__()` must explicitly call `Frame.__init__()` to get it to initialize.
2. The difference between `self.appendToDisplay("7")` and `lambda: self.appendToDisplay("7")` is that in the first case the method `appendToDisplay()` is directly called and the result is returned. When using `lambda` instead of calling the function, a new function is defined. Thus, when using the `lambda` construct the result will not be directly available. Instead the result of the calculation will be delayed to a later time, when the `command` is to be executed. Thus, we want to display `7` on the display when the button is pressed and not now.
3. The `grid` call in `Application.createWidgets()` refers to the button, to place that in the calculator `Application`. The `Application.grid()` call on the other hand, is placing the whole calculator itself. Thus, it is a hierachical thing, where the parts of the application are first placed and then the application itself.

I hope the above answers help you understand the concepts a bit better. It may be quite a bit to digest and you should try to find a few tutorials that explains the concepts in a bit more detail.

Comment: So essentially frame is a superclass? and frame class is initialized by calling init method for its functionalities to be usable later in the code?. Is there a good way of finding what functionalities from frame class were used here? Also, you mentioned that the grid call on widget must be done first before calling grid method on entire calculator app. I am still unclear why we need grid call on the entire application if the grid is taken care of in widget method. Please suggest a topic or concept so I can dig deeper into this. thanks for the help

Comment: There isn't any good way of finding what `Frame`functionality is used. It would require to check all method invocation on the `app` object and that is not so easy, since a lot of that happens in the `calculator.mainloop()`. But for neing able to be used there the `Application` must be a `Frame`.

Comment: The `grid` call in `createWidgets` is done per button. Thus, each button is placed on the grid (which is needed for the object to be shown) of the apllication, But, this still will not place the application itself. For that we need the outer `grid` call. Thus, the buttons are placed in a grid that is not shown until the app itself is placed.

Comment: okay, that makes sense. Thank you for clarifications. I was not expecting to be clear on these concepts this early :)